# Parameterized function for clothoid

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm coding renderer for road network, which based on the [RoadXML](http://www.road-xml.org/) format.

Road curves from this format has four types:

- segment,
- circle arc,
- poly line,
- clotho arc.

And I have problem with the last one.

[Clothoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) is the same with Euler spiral and Cornu spiral. In the RoadXML clotho arc is given by three parameters:

- start curvature,
- end curvature,
- length.

For arc triangulation I need a function like foo(t), which returns (x, y) coords for t = 0..length. I created similar methods for circle arc without problems, but I can't do it for clotho arc.

Part of the problem is that I not totally understand how to apply start and end curvature parameters in standard clothoid formulas.

For example, sample RoadXML road.
[RoadXML sample http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/8172/bigroandabout.png](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/8172/bigroandabout.png)

This is clotho curve item in the red ellipse. It's parameters:

- start curvature = 0,
- end curvature = -0.0165407,
- length = 45.185.

I don't know how to implement these parameters, because clothoid curvature from 0 to -0.0165 is very straight.

I will happy, if you give me a code of this function (in C++, C#, Java, Python or pseudocode) or just a formula, which I can code.

Here is my equations:

```
x(t) ≈ t,
y(t) ≈ (t^3) / 6,
where length = t = s = curvature.

x(-0.0165) = -0.0165,
y(-0.0165) = -7.48688E-07.

Clotho length = 0.0165,
Source length = 45.185.
```

Scaled coords:

```
x'(l) = x / clotho_length * source_length = 45.185,
y'(l) = y / clotho_length * source_length = 5.58149E-07 ≈ 0.

x'(0) = 0,
y'(0) = 0.
```

Thus I get (0, 0)...(45, 0) points, which is very straight.

Where is my mistake? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: btw you know that `k = 1/r`, right? Getting to 60.6m radius of curvature in 45.2 meters is far from straight. :)

Comment: Will Ness, yes, I know, that curvature = 1 / radius. I added my equations into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see. Your data is:

```
start curvature = 0,                straight line, R=INF
end curvature = -0.0165407,         circular arc, R_c = 1/k_c = 60.4569335
length = 45.185.                    distance along clothoid, s_c = 45.185
```

according to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral#Formulation),

```
R s = const = R_c s_c                   ( s ~ k = 1/R by definition of clothoid )
d(s) = R d(theta)
d(theta) = k d(s)
d(theta) / d(s) = 1 / R = k = s / R_c s_c  

theta = s^2 / 2 R_c s_c = (s/a)^2 = s / 2 R = k s / 2 
                               where ___________________
                                     a = sqrt(2 R_c s_c)       (... = 73.915445 )
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and so  theta_c = k_c s_c / 2      (... = 0.37369576475 = 21.411190 degrees )
                                                     ( not so flat after all !! )
```

(note: I call `a` here a reciprocal of what WP article calls `a`). Then,

```
d(x) = d(s) cos(theta)
d(y) = d(s) sin(theta)

x = INT[s=0..s] cos(theta) d(s) 
  = INT[s=0..s] cos((s/a)^2) a d(s/a) 
  = a INT[u=0..(s/a)] cos(u^2) d(u)   = a C( s/a )

y = a INT[u=0..(s/a)] sin(u^2) d(u)   = a S( s/a )
```

where `C(t)` and `S(t)` are [Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

So **that's how you do the scaling**. Not just `t = s`, but **`t = s/a`** `= sqrt(theta)`. Here, for the end point, `t_c = sqrt( k_c s_c / 2) = sqrt( 0.0165407 * 45.185 / 2) = 0.6113066`.

Now, [WolframAlpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B73.915445+Sqrt%5Bpi%2F2%5D+FresnelC%5B0.6113066%2FSqrt%5Bpi%2F2%5D%5D%2C+73.915445+Sqrt%5Bpi%2F2%5D+FresnelS%5B0.6113066%2FSqrt%5Bpi%2F2%5D%5D%7D), `{73.915445 Sqrt[pi/2] FresnelC[0.6113066/Sqrt[pi/2]], 73.915445 Sqrt[pi/2] FresnelS[0.6113066/Sqrt[pi/2]]} =` **`{44.5581, 5.57259}`**. <sup>(Apparently Mathematica uses a [definition scaled with the additional `Sqrt[pi/2]` factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Definition).)</sup>

Testing it with your functions, **`x`** `~= t --> a*(s/a)` **`= 45.185`**, **`y`** `~= t^3/3 --> a*(s/a)^3/3 = 73.915445 * 0.6113066^3 / 3` **`= 5.628481`** (sic! `/3` not `/6`, you have an error there).

So you see, using just the first term from the Taylor series representation of Fresnel integrals is not enough - by far. You have to use more, and stop only when desired precision is reached (i.e. when the last calculated term is less than your pre-set precision value in magnitude).

Note, that if you'll just implement general Fresnel integral functions for one-off scaled clothoid calculation, you'll lose additional precision when you'll multiply the results back by `a` (which is on the order of 10<sup>2</sup> ... 10<sup>3</sup> normally, for roads and railways).

Answer (score 2):

See the paper [The Clothoid, by Ryan Seng and Molly Severdia](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math50c/CalcProj/Fall07/MollyRyan/Paper.pdf).  Generally, clothoids are defined by Fresnel integrals.  It turns out that a clothoid `C(t)` has arclength `t`.  So right off the bat the formula for the general curve is expressed in terms of arclength.  A particular curve is just a subsection of the general spiral, going from start curvature to end curvature.  You would have to do a rotation and translation for the general case.

Comment: Thank you, brainjam, for the link. But my main issue is implementing RoadXML clotho parameters. I add sample into my post.

Comment: "rotation and translation"... and scaling. And you better calculate it so that scaling does not destroy the needed precision.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link no longer works. It's probably this one: https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math50c/CalcProj/Fall07/MollyRyan/Paper.pdf